# crontab every hour into text with format name

Tags: 14.04, cron

I want to make a crontab, which would write content with format name like this :

```
 content_YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.txt // for example: log_20170811_1706.txt
```

Please help me.
I'm Linux novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crontab is the table of cron-jobs, that are executed by the cron daemon, a process that schedules jobs at the times you give it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

In order to write something into a file, you'll have to run `crontab -e` in order to edit the crontab (see also [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)).

In order to write to into a file, which contains the date as name, you'll have to use the date command. For example, `date +"%Y%d%m"` prints what one would call YYYYMMDD. You can get the details of the date format in `man date`.

All in all, you'll have to write something like

```
* * * * * echo "Test" > "/home/myuser/content_"$(date +"\%Y\%d\%m")".txt"
```

to write every minute "Test" into the file of its current date (**EDIT**: like suggested by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), you have to escape the %, instead it will be interpreted as newline by cron). You should have a eye on the fact that this is executed as your user, so you should write in a directory where you have rights to write.