# Copy files from a directory from one system to another system on the same network

Tags: directory, cron, copy

I have below 2 systems with different IPs on the same network

```
A: 192.168.0.20
B: 192.168.0.21
```

From A system I need to copy files from a directory/folder to B system

Also I need to schedule it using crontab so that either all files should be copied or only latest files should be copied.

Answer (score 3):

To transfer a file `myfile` from your local directory to directory `/foo/bar` on machine `otherhost` as user `user`, do:

```
scp myfile user@otherhost:/foo/bar
```

Stolen from [Simplest way to send files over network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197569/246819).

To set up a cron job with that command, see [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/507051).

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync as an alternative. It is mainly for syncing files.. but you can use it for this purpose as well.

```
rsync -avzh --stats --progress remoteuser@remoteip  localpath
```

to add ssh options:

```
rsync -e "ssh -P $port_value" remoteuser@remoteip  localpath
```

`--progress` and `--stats` are useful for real-time display of transfer.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer files/folders to another machine use the `SCP` command.

```
scp localfile user@192.168.0.21:
scp -r localfolder user@192.168.0.21:
```

To Transfer file/folders to another machine with cron you have to configure passwordless login with SSH private key. Then you can use `rsync` command to copy data to another system with crontab.

`rsync` will transfer only updated / new data of your source folder.
[More rsync info and examples here](http://www.fastwebhost.in/blog/13-rsync-command-examples-on-linux/)