# How to open URL in cronjob?

Tags: cron

First upon this is my first question. By using Cronjob I want to open 4 URL every day at 10 am as per Indian time. How can I do this?

Below is given a list of URL.

```
http://www.pragnaprinters.com/Pragna/index.php/Notification/todays_ad

http://www.pragnaprinters.com/Pragna/index.php/Notification/custom_notification

http://www.pragnaprinters.com/Pragna/index.php/Notification/payment_notification

http://www.pragnaprinters.com/Pragna/index.php/Notification/todays_birth
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? You could always use curl to download them.

Comment: I just want to execute PHP code. That's why I want to open this URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
0 10 * * * curl -s "http://www.pragnaprinters.com/Pragna/index.php/Notification/todays_ad" > /dev/null
0 10 * * * curl -s "url 2..." > /dev/null
```

This will run curl, fetching **only** the URL's. It'll ignore redirects and all media on page. It'll be executed at 10:00.

You can add entries to crontab using the command `crontab -e`, further described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job).

If curl is not installed, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install curl`

Curl is also highly customizable and scriptable. `man curl` will give you a overview of this. In the above example `-s` is used to make curl *silent*, so no output is produced.

You can also add the curl commands in a file, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s "url 1" > /dev/null
curl -s "url 2" > /dev/null
```

save the file as for instance `/home/username/bin/curlscript.sh`, and run `chmod +x curlscript.sh`. This can then be used in cron, instead of listing each command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to ask you Where I need to save code that you gave on top?

Comment: In the crontab :) Run crontab -e to bring up the editor. Added a section to the answer.

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'curlscript.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: You need to create the file with your favourite texteditor first. But my answer has two sections. Please follow **either**, not both :) The easiest is to stick with top section; add four lines to your crontab

Comment: Actually, I want to follow full answer but I don't have good knowledge of Ubuntu.