# Editing crontab

Tags: server, permissions, cron

I would like to automate some services using `cron` jobs.

When I try to edit the `crontab` file at `/etc/crontab`, I am not able to save it as it says that it is read only.

What can I do?

Comment: crontab -l to view cron jobs, to edit crontab -e and to delete all cronjobs of a user crontab -r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should note that the reason you got an error specifying that the file is read-only is because you are trying to edit a `root` owned file without being `root`.

If you want to edit `/etc/crontab` you should execute your editor as root -  (e.g. `sudo vi /etc/crontab`).
Note that it isn't the recommended way for regular users

The answer in [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/544264) suggest using `crontab -e` in order to edit the `crontab` file.

Note that `/usr/bin/crontab` is executed as root (set user-id root), and will allow you edit crontab for your own user - the file will be created in this root owned folder `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

If you want to execute crontab services which will run as root You should use `sudo` in order to became root.

You can either update `/etc/crontab` directly by using `sudo vi /etc/crontab` (or use any other text editor) and add a line for your job specifying the user as root...

Or you can run:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Which will edit `root`'s crontab file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: How do I save the crontab I created with sudo crontab -e cause when I create like that and close the terminal, open and write sudo crontab -l it says there are no crontabs for root

Comment: @TheOnlySmartBoy - running `crontab -e` will open your default editor, when you complete writing your crontab rules, you should save the file and exit the editor. You should **NOT** close the terminal at that point. you should first save the file...

Comment: @Zanna - thanks for your comment! I've updated my answer to clarify it.