# How to add and modify CRON jobs

Tags: cron

This is intentionally a duplicate of the following question (because the answers there are not completely correct, and as a new user I somehow cannot comment there): [Editing crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084853/editing-crontab)

ADDED NOTE: The "How do I set up a Cron job?" question too wrongly states that "sudo crontab -e" edits /etc/crontab (it does NOT) - it IS marked as a duplicate of the "Editing crontab" question.

(hoping to get some upvotes here, so I can help correcting wrong answers in the intended way)

Comment: "Intentionally a duplicate" will be promptly closed as a duplicate - nobody will be able to find it. When you have enough reputation, then add your answer to that question.

Comment: How weird - a post motivated by the forum being dysfunctional immediately receives two comments illustrating exactly that. Is no one here interested in getting correct answers? Allow me to point out again - the post marked as a possible duplicate is in error, and exactly the reason why I posted this duplicate question. Who cleans out low-quality answers like that? "sudo crontab -e" does NOT edit /etc/crontab

Comment: There are two things you could do to improve the quality of answers to a question without having any reputation: 1) Post your own, better answer. 2) Suggest (an) edit(s) to any of the answers to make small corrections, fix formatting, add details, etc. If you reach 5 reputation points (suggest 2 edits that are approved), you can also post on meta asking for help improving the Q&A. I'm voting to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking. If you edited it to be more meta, I would vote to migrate to meta. If you removed the meta content, I would vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for trying to give advice, but - how do these referrals to previous duplicate questions with incorrect answers get a fix then? I CANNOT add anything to those questions (neither the latest question nor the previous duplicates), since reputation appears to be needed. I tried to provide a quality answer to the relevant question here.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad, sorry! The question is protected. I've just unprotected it so you can add your answer there. It has had a lot of spam and non-answer answers posted on it, so it'll need to be protected again after you've done so (you can notify me by including @Zanna in a comment here, but other users could also protect the question) The one you linked to in your question is closed as a duplicate so cannot be answered, but the answers can be edited.

Comment: Meanwhile I commented on Yaron's answer to suggest it's misleading at present

Comment: @Zanna, I proposed an answer edit at https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job/2371#2371, mentioning also the /etc/cron.d/ folder which is a lot better than some other suggestions to try to make automatic edits to /etc/crontab or /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root .

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to do that. Unfortunately reviewers rejected your suggestion, despite its correctness and the good edit summary you provided. I've [edited the post myself](https://askubuntu.com/posts/2371/revisions). Is that better? Do feel free to suggest a further edit, but I can't guarantee it will be approved :( Perhaps rather than the section you [proposed adding](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/888832) to the end of the answer being edited in, a new answer could be added with that advice. Would you like to add one?

Answer (score 3):

Per-user CRON jobs are best handled with the `crontab` command, `crontab -l` for showing your own CRON jobs, `crontab -e` for editing (some syntax errors will be detected), and `crontab -r` for removing all your CRON jobs (don't do that...). `sudo crontab` does the same, for the root user.

Duplicate questions have accepted answers that wrongly claim that `sudo crontab -e` edits `/etc/crontab`. It does NOT, it edits `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. I have verified this in Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.

`/etc/crontab` is a system-wide file that can run jobs as any user, typically stored as fragments in `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly`. For precise control of timing and user, add fragments in /etc/cron.d/ .