# How to set automatic job executed every X Hours on Linux?

Tags: backup

I am making several backups every day. I want an scheduled job that will delete some of the backups if they exceed an ammount. I can write an shell script. But how make it work automatically? Is it also possible to run automatic jobs while the computer is locked/suspended?

Comment: You need to set up `cron` job : see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) how to do it.

Comment: As well as setting up `cron` jobs, this site can help you determine the best way to configure your `cron` job.  It's a simulator that shows you your configuration for when it will run the job:  https://crontab.guru/