# how to running script bash with time and date time?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, gnome-terminal

i want to run script.sh with detail time.

for example i want to run script.sh at 15:20 with date 05-01-2023 , how is the command ? please help, I am confused with this problem

Comment: You want to run a specific script on a specific time? Then `cron` is the most tested solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `at` command

```
# To schedule a one time task:
at <time>
<command 0>...
Ctrl-d

# <time> can be either
now | midnight | noon | teatime (4pm)
HH:MM
now + N <minutes | hours | days | weeks>
MM/DD/YY

# To list pending jobs:
atq

# To remove a job (use id from atq):
atrm <id>

 tldr:at 
# at
# Execute commands once at a later time.
# Service atd (or atrun) should be running for the actual executions.
# More information: <https://manned.org/at>.

# Execute commands from standard input in 5 minutes (press `Ctrl + D` when done):
at now + 5 minutes

# Execute a command from standard input at 10:00 AM today:
echo "./make_db_backup.sh" | at 1000

# Execute commands from a given file next Tuesday:
at -f path/to/file 9:30 PM Tue
```